# Unable to access POST parameter values - IIB Esql

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

So I'm quite new to IIB and Extended SQL but what I want to do should be straight forward. I have a REST application which has a resource that is attached to a subflow. What I want to do is to get the input value passed to the service and use it to call a remote web service using the HTTP request node as shown below

```
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestLine.Method = 'POST';
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL = 'http://localhost:8002/MyService';
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.QueryString.RemoteParam= InputLocalEnvironment.REST.Input.Parameters.myValue;
```

What is happening is, when I call the REST method and pass the value as a GET, I'm able to access the value. However, when I pass the parameter value using POST, I'm unable to access the value. My current flow is as follows:

**Input > Compute > HTTPRequest > Compute > Output**

I have searched on Google and applied all recommendations (e.g. setting compute node to LocalEnvironment) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you saying that InputLocalEnvironment.REST.Input.Parameters.myValue is resolving to a null/empty value when you call your API using POST? I suggest that you attach the debugger and monitor the value of that LocalEnvironment field as it passes through the flow. Maybe it's being dropped by a previous node?

Answer (score 1):

Well, we need more information in order to solve your problem but I guess you have problem in your `HTTP request node`

Go to `HTTP request` then in `properties` go to `HTTP setting` and change `HTTP method` to the method that you are using  ( get or post )

and if you want to see if you are fetching data from right property just lunch debugger and put breakepoint in before and after of your nodes, then you can see what data you are receiving in each level and you can call the proper property.

> ps. don't forget to deploy your project again in order to see new
>   changes

I hope that works for you

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I found that IIB does not automatically parse content submitted as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I inserted a trace node and realised that the parameters are instead submitted as a BLOB. All I had to do was read the blob, cast it to a string then use a Split function or a message model to get the individual parameters. Thanks for the pointers